# Visual studio, C++, How to create a relative path in my project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, exe, executable, relative-path

I am trying to run an executable file (in my case mysqldump.exe) from my project.

when I point to the absolute path of the file (in my case `C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySQL\\MySQL Workbench CE 6.1.4\\` ) it works.

The problem is that i want this file to be executed from EVERY PC that runs my program so I decided to move the exe file in the release folder for easier access (and for easier distribution, just copy the release folder).

the problem is how to point to it.

I saw some solutions about macros like `$(IntDir)` but i couldn't get how I can use them.

Thanks in advance for your help!!!

edit: here is my code (it's for backing up a database):

```
        try {
            String^ serverpathsys=----here is the problem----"mysqldump.exe";  
            String^ arguments=" -uroot -pxxxxx tei -r "+this->comboBox3001->Text+"://databasebackup.sql";
            Process::Start(serverpathsys,arguments);    
            MessageBox::Show("completed!");
        }catch (Exception^ ex){
            MessageBox::Show(ex->Message);
        }
```

edit: here is the solution

```
String^ projectpath=Application::StartupPath; //this gets the path
String^ serverpathsys=projectpath + "\\mysqldump.exe"; //and then I add the specific exe
```

here are some links that helped, for future reference:

http://www.rhyous.com/2010/04/16/how-to-use-relative-paths-when-debugging-in-visual-studio-2008/
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/95643/Directory-GetCurrentDirectory

Comment: Where are you using that path? You should be configuring dependencies with something like CMake

Comment: when do you want to run mysqldump.exe? run your exe or compile your project?

Comment: I have edited the question and added my code ;)

Comment: you can put mysqldump.exe in the same folder with your exe, then you first get your exe folder, compose it with mysqldump.exe

Comment: @Jerry.YY i tried with "mysqldump.exe", "Release/mysqldump.exe", "Release//mysqldump.exe", "Release\mysqldump.exe" and "Release\\mysqldump.exe" and nothing worked...

Comment: if you put mysqldump.exe under Release folder, where is your exe path?  you should get your exe path at first, then use it to compose mysqldump.exe path.

Comment: My project's exe is created in the Release folder. In this folder there are 3 files now, myproject.exe, myproject.pdb and mysqldump.exe. How i can get my exe path?

Comment: `nothing worked` - what is the error exactly?

Comment: "The system cannnot find the file specified"

Comment: Check out `GetModuleFilename(NULL)` and use that as a base. Remember, relative filenames are not relative to the executable but relative to a current working directory, which could be anywhere.

Comment: I found the solution!!!! :D I used the Application::StartupPath function to get the path where the exe is located and I passed it into a String^. Then I created a new string that had this string, and the "\\mysqldump.exe". AND IT WORKED! I have updated the first post with the solution!